# Color match with fading colors

Tags: painting, repainting, interior

DIY - interior painting. The colors of the walls have faded, I'd assume after 10+ years? Should I be color-matching in Home Depot with a chip of the existing paint, or using the exact formula that was used to paint the walls 10+ years ago? (I still have the exact formula)

I would assume color-matching would produce better match after the colors may have faded somewhat? Thanks

Edit: this is a patchwork (not whole wall painting job)

Comment: The colour match with the paint chip should match better.  The formula will only match what the paint looked ten years ago when new.  Faded paint will probably be almost a different colour/shade by now, if the two were compared side by side.  Is this for a patch or repainting the whole wall/room?  If repainting go with the formula, unless you like the faded colour.  If patching go with the paint chip match.

Comment: Should edit your question if it is a patch job(small part of a wall) or a repainting of the whole wall.  Two different answers depending on which it is.

Comment: @crip659. Added. Thanks for the answer. Please reply as an answer, will be glad to accept that.

Comment: Even matching the color with the current wall's paint chip, it's very unlikely that it will seamlessly blend in.  The sheen will have changed over the years.  If you want the whole wall to look uniform, you'll be much better off painting the whole wall.  You can probably get away with not painting the whole room (the corners will naturally hide any changes in the paint from 10 years ago).   In addition, unless you get the exact same base (manufacturer, sheen, quality, etc.) it won't blend in invisibly either.